# android convert unix time to utc date

Tags: java, android, java.util.date

I am a little confused with the unix time stamp conversion to java.util.Date involving the time zones.

I have a unix time stamp that is `"1367832568"`. it is a UTC date (Mon May 06 17:29:28 GMT+00:00 2013). when i do following :

```
Date d = new Date(1367832568 * 1000);
```

it gives me `Mon May 06 17:29:28 GMT+08:00 2013` which is not correct. it should give me:

```
Mon May 07 01:29:28 GMT+08:00 2013
```

because the unix time stamp is actually a UTC date. so this is confusing. what should i do to convert the UTC unix time stamp to correctly convert to a UTC Date object.

Comment: try to cast both to long the argument of date: Date d = new Date(((long)1367832568 * (long)1000));

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactely how are you formatting your date object, but by setting the timezone to the dateformat object (to GMT) I'm able to get

> Mon May 06 09:29:28 GMT 2013 AM

which is the same date you are looking for.

```
    long time = 1367832568 * (long) 1000;
    Date date = new Date(time);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy a");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Log.d("date", format.format(date));
```

Comment: i do not want string. i want the date object with GMT date. what you are doing is taking the local GMT date object and using formatter and outputing the GMT string. I need the GMT Date object. the line #2 in your code should give the GMT date object. thats what i want.

Comment: also the date you printed out is not the correct one. i think it changed because of your time zone. the correct output should be Mon May 06 17:29:28 GMT+00:00 2013

Comment: you can't set locale in Date object, use Calendar instead.
and the time is correct according to http://www.epochconverter.com/